# When reinstalling Ubuntu, should I install the latest version or the version originaly installed on the machine?

Tags: 12.04, installation, 11.10

I have inherited a laptop<sup>1</sup> from a colleague that originally came with Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneric Ocelot) installed.

I am planning a clean reinstall of the OS to clean her data and set it up as my machine.

Should I install the latest version of Ubuntu (12.04) or the version that was originally installed (11.10)?

1. Dell Latitude E6230 with Intel Core i7-3520M CPU 2.9 GHz, 64 bit

   The driver info says there are no proprietary drivers but the `Package to workaround e1000e S3 issue` is installed

Comment: The 11.10 has reached its end of life and is not supported. As such if you have any questions about 11.10, it will be considered off topic here. I recommend you go with 13.04, the latest. Do a complete fresh install.

Comment: I would suggest 13.04 as you get all the latest bells and whistles

Comment: @user68186 Wow, it is off topic to ask about old versions! That seems like it is ignoring a lot of collected wisdom.  This isexactly where I would expect people to be able to get help for non-supported versions.

Comment: @KennyPeanuts what graphics card has your Dell Latitude ?! here is same hardware - different brand - running quite good with 12.10 - so 12.04 resp. 12.10 are at moment more "mature" - 'cause fixed and updated.

Comment: Sorry @KennyPeanuts, I didn't make the rules. See the [help on the acceptable topics](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). The newer versions have support for newer hardware. Trying to get old versions to work on newer machines is difficult. In your case, some of workaround needed in 11.10 may be fixed in the later versions. I have used them all, including 12.04, 12.10, and 13.04 and find them all to be fine. A few things that needed workarounds in 12.10 was fixed for me in 13.04.

Comment: @user68186 thanks for the feedback. I went an poked around in meta and found the discussion on it and I can see both sides.  I guess there is also the Unix and Linux SE for questions on older versions, I doubt it would be off topic there (although I have not looked).

Comment: @dschinn1001 The graphics card info is not listed where I thought it would be so I am not sure but it sounds like the consensus is 12.10 or .04 are the way to go.  Thanks for your input

Comment: I'd recommend to only use the LTS versions of Ubuntu. The developers try to mostly add new features between LTS versions, and focus on stability for the LTS versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best choice for your computer is to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Ubuntu 12.04 is a Long Term Support release (LTS), and is supported by updates until April, 2017. Your other available choices are Ubuntu 12.10, which is supported by updates until April, 2014 and Ubuntu 13.04 which is supported by updates until January, 2014.